# Node js sha512 is equivalent to PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, crypt

I am using PHP for admin panel but somehow client needs to integrate frontend in nodejs with pug template engine, i need little help for password encryption, is `sha512('mystring')` of nodejs equivalent to PHP `hash('sha512','mystring')` . ?

I am using this [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512) for node js encryption
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512

For PHP 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Any functional implementation of such an algorithm should produce the same result for a given input.

Comment: `hash('sha512','mystring')` is a [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).  So it's not clear to me exactly how it is implemented. The node.js package is viewable on [GitHub](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha512/blob/master/src/sha512.js) so you can judge if their implementation is suitable. But to answer your question, the node package clearly intends to provide an equivalent service. I would not expect them to produce the same hash given the same input though.

Comment: Implementation may vary but, output hash will remain same.

Comment: Can you please show me any example who generate same output @AtulSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help to someone else

I Got the answer by this Link 
https://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-generate-md5-sha1-sha512-sha256-checksum-hashes-in-node-js.html

```
var sha512 = crypto.createHash('sha512').update('mystring').digest("hex");
```

It's generating same output like php `hash('sha512','mystring')`

Thanks Everyone